# Using .NET Core to create windows applications

Tags: .net, .net-core

Can I create windows services with .NET Core or do I still need using .NET Framework?

Comment: Please go to .NET Framework.

Comment: So it is impossible, right?

Comment: It is not very easy to do. The problem is if you write a core app it should be runnable on Windows, Mac, and Linux. The abilities of a "service" differs per platform by a lot so it was not built in to the 1.x versions. There may be something coming for 2.0 I don't know about, so not posting this as an aswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments the windows service creation is not possible with .NET Core right now.