# Can't create Windows Service that references .NET Core 2.0 assemblies

Tags: console, windows-services, .net-core

I need a non-ASPNET Windows Service (like old style console app).  I know that I can't create a Windows Service in Visual Studio (.NET Framework only) and reference any Core 1/2 assemblies; not allowed.

I want to leverage all the work my other ASPNET projects like database repositories...that are already in Core 2.0.

So...any ideas how I can write a Windows Service that somehow leverages work created in Core Visual Studio projects?

Reference: [Another post on this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358111/using-net-core-to-create-windows-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could make some shared assemblies .NET Standard instead of .NET Core and then use these shared assemblies in a .NET Framework windows service, there are other options at making a .NET Core based windows service.

The first one would be to use [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/) (currently in preview) which allows using the `ServiceBase` class in .NET Core when running on windows.

Another option would be to use the `DasMulli.Win32.ServiceUtils` NuGet package which allows creating windows services both on .NET Core and .NET Framework with an API a little different to `ServiceBase` - see [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service). (disclaimer: package developed by myself for use at the company I work at)

Comment: Quick test using Windows Compatibility Pack does work...allows me to write Core 2.0 Console app (using ServiceBase) and reference other Core projects.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update to the Answer**

Based on the *Martin's* answer  and comment Now you can use  **Windows Compatibility Pack** for the purpose.

---

<del>Yes,a netcoreapp can not be referenced by net framework project.</del> This document at https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md shows the compatibility matrix. <del>According to that net framework can only refer to compatible netstandard projects.</del>

And further according to [Api reference for ServiceBase Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=netframework-4.7.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.0) , `ServiceBase` class is available only in net framework.

---

One option comes in to my mind to leverage netcoreapp projects in a windows services is creating a multi target project with netcore2.0 and net471 or make the coreapp project a multi target, with conditional compilation.

Add a conditional reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices` in csproj. Then conditionally call `host.RunAsService` and `host.Run` in `program.cs`.

For more info about multi target   and windows services please have a look at

1. [How to Multitarget section in Developing Libraries with cross platform tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget)
2. [Host an ASP.NET Core app in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service)